# Proper way of having a unique identifier in Python?

Tags: python, identifier

Basically, I have a list like: `[START, 'foo', 'bar', 'spam', eggs', END]` and the START/END identifiers are necessary for later so I can compare later on. Right now, I have it set up like this:

```
START = object()
END = object()
```

This works fine, but it suffers from the problem of not working with pickling. I tried doing it the following way, but it seems like a terrible method of accomplishing this:

```
class START(object):pass
class END(object):pass
```

Could anybody share a better means of doing this? Also, the example I have set up above is just an oversimplification of a different problem.

Comment: I think it would be better to just call it a simplification rather than "an oversimplification"

Comment: Since what you're doing is very complicated (with no explanation of why), I would call it a "complication" or perhaps an "overcomplication".  Sentinel objects are essentially useless -- there are far, far better ways to organize data.

Comment: S: that would have been a helpful comment if you had included some explanation of one of the "far, far better" ways.  As it is, it just seems crabby and condescending.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Crabby, perhaps.  Nested lists/tuples can generally replace anything with sentinels.  Any nested list/tuple has all the implicit sentinel structure it needs.  However, since the question is relatively incomplete, it's hard to suggest a better structure other than the vague "please rethink you approach; you don't need sentinels when you have nested lists."

Comment: When I needed a sentinel value, it was to provide an object you could pass to a function that indicated a "wildcard" value.  The function was supposed to treat the wildcard value specially, no matter where or how many times it appeared in the input.  I'll agree that with good containers you won't often need sentinels to mark beginning or end of data, but there will always be sentinels used for "out of band" flags.  As an example, many Python functions use `None` as a sort of sentinel value; when you pass `None` it detects this special case and provides a default value of some sort.

Comment: @steveha: "out of band" and "sentinel" don't match up well in my mind, and don't match this question very well at all.  "out of band" usually means a class hierarchy with "in band" in one part of the hierarchy and "out of band" as a disjoint subclass from the "in band" stuff.  But that doesn't help with this question, which is -- I think -- doing something simple in a far too complex manner.

Comment: @S.Lott: we don't really know what the actual code is doing; he might have a good reason for wanting some out-of-band value.  (Perhaps you don't like my use of that phrase; I'll accept some other if it makes you happier.  But clearly any sentinel cannot appear in the data it terminates, so you have a subclass, "data which can appear in the list", and a larger class, that subclass plus any sentinels.  Does this not meet your definition?)  In any event, you have effectively communicated your displeasure with his example, and either he has a good reason, or he now has a chance to rethink things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want an object that's guaranteed to be unique **and** can also be guaranteed to get restored to exactly the same identify if pickled and unpickled right back, top-level functions, classes, class instances, and if you care about `is` rather than `==` also lists (and other mutables), are all fine.  I.e., any of:

```
# work for == as well as is
class START(object): pass
def START(): pass
class Whatever(object): pass
START = Whatever()

# if you don't care for "accidental" == and only check with `is`
START = []
START = {}
START = set()
```

None of these is terrible, none has any special advantage (depending if you care about `==` or just `is`).  Probably `def` wins by dint of generality, conciseness, and lighter weight.

Comment: I prefer option #1 of using the class as the sentinel, because it gives the most informative exceptions--you get AttributeError's that identify the value that failed.  It is a bit weird though in that it will let you create objects, but there's no simple way of preventing that, and it's really not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `Symbol` class for handling START and END.

```
class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Symbol) and other.value == self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<sym: %r>" % self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

START = Symbol("START")
END = Symbol("END")

# test pickle
import pickle
assert START == pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(START))
assert END == pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(END))
```

Comment: I was actually doing it this way for a while.

Comment: Then why do you want to switch to some other approach? In fact some other languages have built-in support for symbols. In Ruby, you can write `:start` and `:end` for start and stop symbols.

Comment: In Python, string are intended to be used as symbols. Except sometimes we also want to use strings, so we need these other approaches

Answer (score 1):

If your list didn't have strings, I'd just use "start", "end" as Python makes the comparison O(1) due to interning.

If you do need strings, but not tuples, the complete cheapskate method is:

```
[("START",), 'foo', 'bar', 'spam', eggs', ("END",)]
```

PS: I was sure your list was numbers before, not strings, but I can't see any revisions so I must have imagined it

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I like your solution.

A while back I was hacking on a Python module, and I wanted to have a special magical value that could not appear anywhere else.  I spent some time thinking about it and the best I came up with is the same trick you used: declare a class, and use the class object as the special magical value.

When you are checking for the sentinel, you should of course use the `is` operator, for object identity:

```
for x in my_list:
    if x is START:
        # handle start of list
    elif x is END:
        # handle end of list
    else:
        # handle item from list
```

Comment: If you declare your own class == will only check identity by default

Comment: True, but I wouldn't recommend it.  If you write `==` when you really mean `is`, you aren't clearly expressing your intent.  And I'm not sure how likely it is, but it is possible someone could write a class whose `__cmp__()` method returns 0 when it compares to your sentinel class.  (I just wrote one as a proof of concept...)  If you use `is` you know exactly what it will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this would be easier to answer if you were more explicit about what you need this for, but my inclination if faced with a problem like this would be something like:

```
>>> START = os.urandom(16).encode('hex')
>>> END = os.urandom(16).encode('hex')
```

Pros of this approach, as I'm seeing it

- Your markers are strings (can pickle or otherwise easily serialize, eg to JSON or a DB, without any special effort)
- Very unlikely to collide either accidentally or on purpose
- Will serialize and deserialize to identical values, even across process restarts, which (I think) would not be the case for `object()` or an empty class.

Cons(?)

- Each time they are newly chosen they will be completely different. (This being good or bad depends on details you have not provided, I would think).

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work if I pickle the result and open it up in a separate process since now each one is different.

Comment: I *really* don't like this solution (I know the chance of collision is small, but if it happens you are really stuffed!), but you did list the limitations, so I am resisting my urge to downvote

Comment: @Casebash Does 1/2^64 seem an unreasonably high probability to you, or do you have reason to believe /dev/*random is broken?